# There is a question here that is outdated. How can we flag questions?

Tags: support, flagging, protected-questions

I am unable to provide an answer to a question because, apparently, I'm a noob. Yet, I can clearly see there is a question here that needs to be removed because it is outdated due to an iOS update. The info on the question is moot and anyone coming here would likely be mislead by the answers. How can noobs also alert the community that some posts need to be flagged as old and new information added?  The question I'm referring to right now is: [How to make a duplicate of a photo on iPhone before I crop or edit it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126550/how-to-make-a-duplicate-of-a-photo-on-iphone-before-i-crop-or-edit-it?newreg=999c4c9b5b2e476c97f11614b4ec958e). This issue no longer exists since Apple added a 'duplicate' button under the share function.

Comment: Not every one has the latest OS and the top rated answer starts by saying that Apple have released a version with the duplicate button

Comment: Yes, now there's an answer. I didn't see that when I first went there.

Answer (score 3):

That particular question was automatically protected by the site due to the quantity of ‘answers’ the post received from new users posting things which weren't answers. Protected questions are an extreme minority of the questions on this site and it's unfortunate that it prevented a legitimate answer from you.

I have unprotected the question — go ahead and provide your answer, we wouldn't want to miss out on the knowledge you want to share!

Once you have a small amount of reputation here (e.g. one accepted answer), you may [flag posts for moderator attention](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: Thank you, but someone has since answered it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, questions that are "outdated" are not in need of removal, but rather in need of editing to clarify that they apply to certain versions of an operating system and not to others.

An answer that applies to Lion but not High Sierra isn't wrong or unhelpful, but does need to be edited to make clear in what contexts it is helpful.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. It was annoying because I clearly had the updated answer at the time but couldn't add it.